# Display specific records only in jqGrid?

Tags: jqgrid, records

How do I display specific records only in jqGrid?

For example, after a user login only select records will display
according to the username that is logged in?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display specific records only in jqGrid?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6295655/display-specific-records-only-in-jqgrid)

Answer (score 0):

Oleg's answer to the dupe question is right, you should typically limit the data you send to the page from the server based on the request.

It is also possible to make decisions using the grid loadComplete method:

```
loadComplete: function (data) {
   if (data.rows.length > 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < data.rows.length; i++) {
         if ([condition]) {
             $("#" + data.rows[i].Id).css("display", "none");
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest small performance improvement. I recommend you to use native implemented [namedItem](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_table_cells.asp) method of the row of the [table DOM element](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_table.asp): `$(this.rows.namedItem(data.rows[i].Id)).hide();`instead of `$("#" + data.rows[i].Id).css("display", "none");`. The `namedItem` is more quickly as $('#'+rowid).