# Display specific records only in jqGrid?

Tags: php, jquery, jqgrid

How do I display specific records only in jqGrid?

For example a user login then the jqGrid should display records that is related to the user logged-in only.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display specific records only in jqGrid?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6295243/display-specific-records-only-in-jqgrid)

Answer (score 1):

You would handle this in your PHP code. You would have to read from your PHP code who the user is, and query your database to only get the relevant information. You shouldn't try to handle this on the client side.